# Mercado Pago da de baja TLS 1.0 y no se como arreglarlo

Tags: mercadopago

me enviaron un mail avisandome que iban a dar de baja el TLS 1.0 y que me fijara si lo utilizo. Ingrese a http://beta.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/pci-compliant-merchants/disabling-tls-10 pero lo logro entender donde me debo fijar si estoy utilizando esto.

Estoy utilizando la API de MP en PHP y la versión de la API es la 0.1.9, ahora la voy a actualizar por la 0.5.3. Pero aun así no se si estoy cubierto con el cambio que van a hacer.

Alguien le paso esoto?

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para lo mismo
y también puedes revisar [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para ver si es pertinente preguntar sobre el tema. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo acá:

> En consecuencia, Mercado Pago requerirá que sus conexiones a los
>   dominios https://api.mercadopago.com y
>   https://pagamento.mercadopago.com sean a través del protocolo de
>   cifrado TLS 1.1 o superior a partir del 30 de Junio del 2018.

el cambio solo te afecta si tenés formulario de pago integrado en el sitio. Botones de pago y redirecciones no tendrían problemas.

Para confirmar que no vas a tener problemas:

- Usar https en tu sitio
- Confirmar que la conexión usa el protocolo TLS 1.1 o 1.2. Desde chrome, f12 para abrir la consola devtools y en la pestaña de seguridad te muestra esa información:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
  En mi server soporto TLS 1, 1.1 y 1.2

En caso de que la conexión sea TLS 1.0 deberías modificar la configuración de tu server (dependiendo si es nginx o apache será distinto) para que soporte TLS 1.1 y 1.2

Nginx: https://embrolio.com/entry/certificado-ssl-con-let-s-encrypt-y-ajustes-a-nginx (perdón por el autobombo, ya lo hice en su momento y lo documenté ahi)

Apache: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/ssl/ssl_howto.html

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**
Tiene razón Joel, también hay que validar que la versión de TLS que usa la app que se comunica con MercadoPago sea 1.1 o 1.2

Comment: Espectacular Amiazo !!! Acá veo, TLS 1.3 asique me quedo mas tranquilo. Mil Gracias.

Comment: Tener en cuenta también validar que la aplicación. la cual se esta integrando MercadoPago debe comunicarse con el servidor de MP usando protocolo distinto a TLS 1.0, para ello se puede enviar un request desde la aplicación pueden usar esta tool https://tls-v1-1.badssl.com:1011/